# How to target specific material with Unity VideoPlayer?

Tags: unity, materials, video

I've modeled the following tv-monitor:
[image: tv-monitor]

This monitor has two materials. The "frame" that makes up the monitor, called `MonitorFrameMaterial` and the black screen material, called `MonitorScreenMaterial`.

I've added the `Video Player` to the monitor and would like to play a video "on the screen material".
Here's a screenshot of the inspector:
[image: inspector]

**I've already searched the web for some time to find an answer, but I can't seem to find a way to play the video on the screen. Whenever I add a video now, it actually targets the monitor-frame (probably because it's the first material?).**

Is there any way to change this, and if yes, how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create a RenderTexture in your project with the width and height matching your VideoClip for best performance.
Change RenderMode from MaterialOverride to RenderTexture
Set the RenderTexture you've created as TargetTexture of your VideoPlayer component and set it also Albedo Property of your material